# Can't get AJAX response to appear inside a DIV

Tags: php, jquery

$catlistThis is a jQuery POST using AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#taglist').change(function(){
        $.post('../includes/ajax.php', { taglist: $(this).find("option:selected").attr('value')}, function(data) {
        $("#catid").html(response.catlist);
    });
    });
});
```

And this is is what happens in ajax.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['taglist'])){
    $catlist = '<select name="cat_id[]" size="5" multiple id="cat_id[]" class="darkgrey w200px">';
    $catlist .= '<option value="123">123</option>';
    $catlist .= '<option value="456">456</option>';
    $catlist .= '</select>';
    echo json_encode(array("status"=>"success", "catlist" => $catlist));
}
```

In my real page I will be populating the cat_id select with values depending on the POST. For testing purposes I'm just returning a static select with 2 options.

For some reason I cant grasp, I can't seem to get the response to appear inside #catid although the post and response are carried out fine (I'm using the Firebug Net panel for monitoring the Post and Response). Please give me your lights on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed that you have no echo related to variable $catlist

```
 echo json_encode(array("status"=>"success", "catlist" => "abc"));
```

should be some thing like

```
echo json_encode(array("status"=>"success", "catlist" => $catlist));
```

And you AJAX response code should be updated

```
$("#catid").html(response.catlist);
```

replaced with

```
$("#catid").html(data.catlist);
```

**EDIT:** I exactly haven't got what exactly your problem is after above solution but one i thing I can guess is you might be having issue due to json encode you have made on server side in php for that you have to have following chnages in your code.

```
var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
$("#catid").html(response.catlist);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, my code was "catlist" => $catlist but for the sake of debugging I had temporarily changed it to something more simple.

Comment: Ok, and how could I return the response as options of a given select of id #cat_id? 
I tried $("#cat_id").innerHtml(data.catlist) but without luck.

Comment: #cat_id is the id of select box(while #catid is the id of div box). 
In your particular example "data" is response variable which contain 2 things status & catlist, where status will have "success" and catlist will have the complete select box. In order to draw your select box you should use id_of_div and set its innerHTML property to the response of AJAX which contains the select box.

Are you trying to set the response directly to the selectbox???

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#taglist').change(function(){
        $.post('../includes/ajax.php', {taglist:$(this).find("option:selected").attr('value')}, function(data) {
          $("#catid").html(data.catlist);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I see. I was using response.catlist instead of data.catlist, does that mean I was referencing the entire response instead of just the portion I required?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#taglist').change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '../includes/ajax.php',
            taglist: $(this).find("option:selected").attr('value'),
            success: function(data) {
                $("#catid").html(response.catlist);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This is what I originally used and I'm afraid it doesn't work.